# colorWithPatternImage turns image upside down?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a CAShapeLayer which I'm filling it with an image.However, the image is turning upside down...

```
 CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [[self makeCircleAtLocation:location radius:100.0] CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0f green:30/255.0f blue:30/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    [self.dd.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:previewImageView.image].CGColor; //turned upside down inside the circle
```

Comment: Where did you get image? Is it photo? If so, problem could be in photo metadata (orientation).

Comment: It can be a picture taken with camera or chosen from the photo library...

Answer (score 0):

So problem could be in image metadata. It is contain image orientation. I use this method to get rid of it:

```
+ (UIImage *)normalizeImageOrientation:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultImage;
}
```